# On one worksheet, I want to conditionally format cells (N552:N579) which pull dates from (O6:O443) to shade gray if the dates in O6:O443 are formula

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

All information is on one worksheet.  I have dates in **some** of the cells in O6:O443.  Some of those dates are the result of the formula =TODAY()+7*26.  Further down on the worksheet I have dates in column N (N552:N579) which use a (very lengthy) formula to pull the dates from O6:O443.  I would like to shade all cells in N552:N579 if the date that is pulled from O6:O443 is the result of a formula.  I have project numbers on both sets of data that can be used to do a VLOOKUP if necessary.  I have tried VLOOKUP; IF function, ISFORMULA function; and various combinations of these.  I either get NO shaded cells or ALL the cells are shaded.

Comment: `=TODAY()+7*26` is a formula, why are you surprised `ISFORMULA` returns true? This looks like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Not all of the dates in the O6:O443 range use the =today()+7*26 formula.  I want to highlight ONLY the cells in range N552:N579 that are pulling the dates from the O6:O443 range which DO use the formula.  However, I either get all cells highlighted or none.  Not just those that trace back to the cells with the date formula.  I'm sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? i.e. what is the greater purpose of highlighting cells based on if other cells have a formula?

Comment: Because it saves having to trace back and look to determine if the date was calculated or entered manually.  Various people use that information in various ways, whether for shipping purposes, warranty information, etc.